# concat in php codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, concatenation

Please help me to understand proper join syntax.

I have table named *inventory* which has:

```
trans_id    
trans_items items -> item_id         
trans_user  employees -> person_id           
trans_date                   
trans_comment                
trans_inventory
```

As you can see above, trans_items is a foreign key in items table, and trans_user is a foreign key in employees table and employee id is foreign key to people table.

Now what I want to do is to display in HTML the inventory table, but instead of displaying the employee id, I want the employee NAME to be displayed.

---

EDIT................................................
so i was enable to display only the last name of the employee with this code:

```
$this->db->select('inventory.*, items.name ,people.last_name');
$this->db->from('inventory');
$this->db->join('items', 'inventory.trans_items = items.item_id' , 'left');
$this->db->join('people', 'inventory.trans_user = people.person_id' , 'left');
$this->db->where('deleted', 0);
$this->db->order_by('trans_date desc');
```

with the model code:

```
foreach($report_data as $row)
        {
            $tabular_data[] = array($row['name'], $row['last_name'],$row['trans_date'], $row['trans_inventory'], $row['trans_comment']);
        }
```

but i need it to be first name and last name so i did these:

```
$this->db->select('inventory.*, items.name ,CONCAT(people.first_name, " ",people.last_name) as employee');
$this->db->from('inventory');
$this->db->join('items', 'inventory.trans_items = items.item_id' , 'left');
$this->db->join('people', 'inventory.trans_user = people.person_id' , 'left');
$this->db->where('deleted', 0);
$this->db->order_by('trans_date desc');
```

with the model code:

```
foreach($report_data as $row)
        {
            $tabular_data[] = array($row['name'], $row['employee'],$row['trans_date'], $row['trans_inventory'], $row['trans_comment']);
        }
```

it would error if i would use concat function. please help.

Comment: @AntonioCS: In response to your flag, the `mysql` tag is being added to the title for SEO purposes.  See the discussions at [Does the order of keywords matter in a page title?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6556/does-the-order-of-keywords-matter-in-a-page-title) and [Why is the first tag sometimes in the <title> tag of some questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71922/why-is-the-first-tag-sometimes-in-the-title-tag-of-some-questions).

Answer (score 22):

Your select must be like this (second parameter in $this->db->select('your select part', FALSE) ):

```
$this->db->select('inventory.*, items.name ,CONCAT(people.first_name, " ",people.last_name) as employee', FALSE);
$this->db->from('inventory');
$this->db->join('items', 'inventory.trans_items = items.item_id' , 'left');
$this->db->join('people', 'inventory.trans_user = people.person_id' , 'left');
$this->db->where('deleted', 0);
$this->db->order_by('trans_date desc');
```

Quote from Codeigniter manual:

> If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter
>   will not try to protect your field or
>   table names with backticks. This is
>   useful if you need a compound select
>   statement.

Comment: Thank you so much...Your answer really helped to understand why error was occuring :)

Comment: Thankyou for telling about the second variable "FALSE" :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$query=$this->db->select("id, CONCAT(nombre,".' '.",apellido_paterno) as nombre", false)->
                                from("empleado")->
                                where('empleado', $filtro)->
                                order_by("nombre")->
                                get();
```

only add false to select