# Codeigniter concat and join

Tags: codeigniter

I want to concat 2 fields together in my codeigniter db query but its not working, can you help me please?

```
$this->db->select('*, news.id as news_id, news.created as created_on, CONCAT(users.firstname, users.surname) as article_author, CONCAT(modified_user.firstname, modified_user.surname) as modified_author');
$this->db->join('users', 'users.id = news.author', 'left');
$this->db->join('users modified_user', 'modified_user.id = news.modified_by', 'left');
```

Thanks

Comment: What error do you get? Do you have from(TABLE)/get(TABLE) part? show whole active record query so we can figure sth out

Comment: Provide more information with your question please.

Answer (score 3):

At a minimum, you're missing a `->from`. This means you have nothing to join to.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is the complete one? Try adding the get function:

```
$this->db->select('*, news.id as news_id, news.created as created_on, CONCAT(users.firstname, users.surname) as article_author, CONCAT(modified_user.firstname, modified_user.surname) as modified_author')->join('users', 'users.id = news.author', 'left')->join('users modified_user', 'modified_user.id = news.modified_by', 'left');
$this->db->get('TableName');
```

Do you get any error? You could also try printing the query with:

```
print_r( $this->db->last_query() );
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using CONCAT you need to pass FALSE as an argument after your select statement. Like so:

```
$this->db->select('*, news.id as news_id, news.created as created_on, CONCAT(users.firstname, users.surname) as article_author, CONCAT(modified_user.firstname, modified_user.surname) as modified_author',FALSE);
```

$this->db->join('users', 'users.id = news.author', 'left');

$this->db->join('users modified_user', 'modified_user.id = news.modified_by', 'left');

see this answer:
[concat in php codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623958/concat-in-php-codeigniter)